# Redis Cache Clear C#

Tags: c#, azure-redis-cache

I try to remove data by using the method above

```
public virtual void ClearOrderTypeCache()
{
    orderTypeList = null;
    cacheService.Set<OrderTypeProjection[]>(orderTypeCacheKey, null);
}
```

But I've got an exception when I try to use it

```
ICacheService.Set<OrderTypeProjection[]>("189b5a92-e728-405a-b13a-e3b62c870845-OrderTypes", null) 
invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help.

You are creating a Mock<>, which uses MockBehavior.Strict by default which

> MockBehavior.Strict : Causes the mock to always throw an exception for
>   invocations that don't have a corresponding setup.
>
> Somewhere in your code you are invoking members that have no setup
>   configured. I suggest create a setup for all members you intend to
>   invoke during your tests
>
> like this:
>
> ```
> var httpStatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;//or what ever you want it to be
> responseMessage.Setup(m => m.StatusCode).Returns(httpStatusCode);
> responseMessage.Setup(m => m.ReadContentAsString()).Returns("Put your return string here");
> ```